# Data saved in arraylist is returning null when arraylist called in custom adapter?

Tags: android, arraylist

I am facing the problem in JSON data from server is saved in the ArrayList is returning null when the ArrayList is called in the custom adapter. The custom adapter is used to list the data in the spinner in android.

```
public class PhotoCommnFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    EditText rechargeMobileNumber,rechargeAmount;
    Spinner selectMenu;
    int flags[] = {R.drawable.airteltv, R.drawable.aircel, R.drawable.dishtv, R.drawable.sundirect, R.drawable.tatasky, R.drawable.videocon};
    List<SpinnerMenu> selectedNetwork = new ArrayList<>();
    public PhotoCommnFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_mobile, container, false);
        mobileRecahrgeHistory();
        rechargeMobileNumber = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recharge_mobile_number);
        rechargeAmount = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recharge_amount);
        selectMenu = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.selectNetwork);
        settingSpinnerDropDown();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void mobileRecahrgeHistory(){
        Ion.with(this)
                .load("http://192.168.1.105/TotalRecharge/?api=ol&uid=1")
                .asJsonObject().withResponse()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> result) {
                        JSONObject json = null;

                        try {
                            json = new JSONObject(result.getResult().toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // Create the root JSONObject from the JSON string.
                        JSONObject jsonRootObject = null;
                        jsonRootObject = json.optJSONObject("DS");

                        //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("LST");

                        //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
                        for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                            try {
                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String iph = null;

                            String oid = jsonObject.optString("OID").toString();
                            String ocd = jsonObject.optString("OCD").toString();
                            String opd = jsonObject.optString("OPE").toString();
                            String mil = jsonObject.optString("MIL").toString();
                            String mxl = jsonObject.optString("MXL").toString();
                            try {
                                 iph = jsonObject.getString("IPH").toString();
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            String urldisplay = "http://192.168.1.105/TotalRecharge/"+iph;
                            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                            try {
                                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                            } catch (Exception e3) {
                                e3.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            SpinnerMenu spinnerData = new SpinnerMenu();
                            spinnerData.setOid(oid);
                            spinnerData.setOcd(ocd);
                            spinnerData.setOpd(opd);
                            spinnerData.setMil(mil);
                            spinnerData.setMix(mxl);
                            spinnerData.setImage(mIcon11);

                            selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);

                        }

                    }

                });
    }


    public void settingSpinnerDropDown(){
        Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter customAdapter=new Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items,R.id.serviceName,selectedNetwork);
        selectMenu.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
```

In the above code the json data from the server is saved in a  `selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);` in ArrayList but when I call the saved arraylist data inside the:

```
Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter customAdapter=new Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items,R.id.serviceName,selectedNetwork);
```

in this the ArrayList is returning null when the data is passed  in custom adapter.

When I checked by  debugging the JSON data are saved in the ArrayList but when it called in adapter is returning null.

I don't know what error in this. Please help me how to solve this.   `

The below code is setting the data in custom adatapter

```
 public class Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerMenu> {
        Context context;
    int flags[];
    List<SpinnerMenu> countryNames;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter(FragmentActivity activity, int resouceId, int textviewId, List<SpinnerMenu> data) {


   //     super(activity, R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items,userstories);
        super(activity,resouceId,textviewId,data);
        this.countryNames = data;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView names;
        ImageView icon;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater  = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items, parent, false);
   //     convertView = inflter.inflate(fragment_dth_main_spinner_items, null);
        SpinnerMenu spinnerData = countryNames.get(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        View result;

        if(convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
             viewHolder.names = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serviceName);
            result = convertView;
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }
//        viewHolder.icon.setImageBitmap(spinnerData.getImage());
        viewHolder.names.setText(spinnerData.getOpd());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In the above code viewHolder.name.setText(); the value is returning null. I tried but still its returning null.I don't know what wrong in this method.

Comment: post your code for Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding items to the `selectedNetwork` array, add them to the adapter. e.g.

```
private Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter customAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    ...

    customAdapter = new Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter(getActivity(),
        R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items,
        R.id.serviceName,
        new ArrayList<SpinnerMenu>() );
}
```

and then replace:

```
selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);
```

with

```
customAdapter.add(spinnerData);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happened because your `mobileRecahrgeHistory()` method is calling the following code:

```
Ion.with(this)
   .load("http://192.168.1.105/TotalRecharge/?api=ol&uid=1")
   .asJsonObject().withResponse()
   .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {

     ...
     selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);
     ...
   }
```

which is **Asynchronous**. the `settingSpinnerDropDown();` is already finished when the `mobileRecahrgeHistory` is finish.

So you need to tell the adapter that its data is changed using something like `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

Comment: How can i get the saved from the arraylist

Comment: You need to call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);`

Comment: Null value is returning

Comment: At a glance, I don't find any error in your adapter. Could you make sure that the `selectedNetwork` is filled with the data? Use `Log.d()` to check.

Comment: add `Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter customAdapter=new Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items,R.id.serviceName,selectedNetwork);
        selectMenu.setAdapter(customAdapter);` after      `selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);`

Comment: When i add the Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter customAdapter=new Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter(getActivity(),R.layout.fra‌​gment_dth_main_spinn‌​er_items,R.id.servic‌​eName,selectedNetwor‌​k); selectMenu.setAdapter(customAdapter); afetr selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);  the  null pointer exception is shown in customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is added after the selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);

Comment: But when i add Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter customAdapter = new Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter
               (getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items,R.id.serviceName,selectedNetwork);
       selectMenu.setAdapter(customAdapter);  created inside onCreateView() means the null pointer exception is shown in viewholder.name.setText()

Comment: don't use `notifyDataSetChanged` because you're initializing the data there.

Comment: Instead of notifyDataSetChanged() what should i use there

Comment: you don't need anything other than set the adapter. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-Input-Views#spinners

Comment: I can't understand your answer